# What does this probability notation denote: $P( Y=y | X =x)$?

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning

What does this probability notation denote: $P( Y=y | X =x)$?
I came across this while looking at my notes for optimal prediction rule.

> Optimal prediction rule:
>       for each $x ∈ X$ , chose $y ∈ Y$ with maximum $\Pr[Y = y | X = x]$.

Comment: Conditional probability.

Comment: $P(Y=y\mid X)(X=x)$ usually.